# Executing PHP code from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am developing a php page containing a drop down select button. On changing its value, I am calling a javascript method and passing value selected in drop down. Now I want to use the value passed to get further details from MySql using PHP. How can I write PHP code withing javascript? 
I am a beginner to PHP. Suggest me a simple and easiest way to do this

Comment: To achieve this, you have to learn `AJAX`

Comment: AJAX is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

For onchange event of dropdown, you can call php page using ajax and passing your params and get the output.

Comment: It would be nice to elaborate with a link to an example or at least a basic overview on how it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ajax like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)
 and [this](http://coursesweb.net/ajax/multiple-select-dropdown-list-ajax_t) (http://coursesweb.net/ajax/multiple-select-dropdown-list-ajax_t)

Answer (score 0):

Front-end client side script (Javascript) can't directly 'invoke' or run PHP code. This is because of the separation between client side (browser) and server side (server) components of a web page. When you make a normal request to a server to return a page (eg. index.html), it will return the content of the page and terminate the execution.

What you're trying to achieve is something called AJAX, which is described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). There's also a pretty good and basic example of how to run a PHP script from Javascript.

In basic terms, AJAX is an asynchronous execution of the server side component of a web page. You can target a page 'test.php' with an ajax request, much the same was as you would when you open the page in your browser, and the content of the page would be returned.

To get the additional content, you can use either a POST ($_POST) or GET($_GET) request to send details back to the server. Typically when you're performing a search, you would use GET. If you're performing an update or create, you would use POST.

So your page URL might be something like http://mywebsite.dev/ajax.php?select=apples (where mywebsite.dev is the development URL). If you have a table of apple types, your MySQL query would be:

```
$type = $_GET['select'];
// Do some filtering on $type, eg. mysql_real_escape_string() and a few others
SELECT fruit.types FROM fruit WHERE fruit.main_type = '$type';
```

And then return a formatted JSON object back to the browser:

```
$return = Array(
    0 => 'Pink Lady',
    1 => 'Sundowner',
    2 => 'Granny Smith',
    ...
);

$json = json_encode($return);

// expected result
{['Pink Lady'],['Sundowner'],['Granny Smith']};
```

You can always give extra indexes to arrays (multi-dimensional) or use stdClass to give better structure.

Then in your Javascript you use a for loop to iterate over the json object to build a new list of options.

```
var output = '';
for (var i = 0, k = json.length; i < k; i++) {
    output += '<option value="' + json[i] + '">' + json[i] + '</option>';
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for this you need to use ajax.
 try :

index.php code : This script will grab data from from using jquery and post it to search.php file via ajax

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#userid').change(function(){
                userid=this.value;
                $.ajax({
                    url:'search.php',
                    data : 'userid='+userid,
                    type:'POST',
                    success:function(result){
                        $('#result_div').html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='getUserData' id='getUserData' action='#' method='GET'>
        Select User : <select id='userid' name='userid'>
            <option value='1'>Lokendra</option>
            <option value='2'>Amit</option>
            <option value='3'>Nitin</option>
            <option value='4'>Rishabh</option>
        </select>

    </form>
    <div id='result_div'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

search.php code : This file will contain you business logic . and return value to ajax success method. You can fill retrun result any container.

```
<?php
        $userArray=array(
                    1   =>  'Lokendra',
                    2   =>  'Amit',
                    3   =>  'Nitin',
                    4   =>  'Rishabh',
                );
        $postedData=$_REQUEST;
        // Fire your select query here and diplay data 

        if(isset($postedData['userid'])){
            echo "Selected User name =>".$userArray[$postedData['userid']];die;
        }
    ?>
```

Dont forget to accept answer if it helps you. :)